# Passing a string value to JS funtion code on submit

Tags: javascript

I'm sending a user input (string) to a third party API, I should expect a JSON results in `<p class="score">` Nothing happens! The `userinput` is not passed to the Javascript but it's accessible via `alert` Can someone please let me know if there's a problem with syntax?

```js
var myurl = 'https://apiv2.coolcompany.io/sentiment';
var api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


function ApiRequest() {

    var mydata = document.getElementById('userinput').value;

    $.post(
      myurl,
        JSON.stringify({
        'api_key': api_key,
        'data': mydata,

      }).then(function(sent) { 

        var s = sent
        var obj = JSON.parse(s)

        $('.score').append(obj.results)

 });
```

```html
<input placeholder="I love writing code!" id="userinput">    

<button onclick="ApiRequest()" id="submit">Try It</button>

<p class="score">Score : </p>
```

Comment: where are you exactly passing the string?
Are you aware that mydata should be an object?

Comment: maybe add it as a text instead`$('.score').text("Score : " + obj.results)`

Comment: try using `.done` instead of `.then`, as shown in the example in the jquery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Look at your Developer Tools console tab, do you see any errors? Since you are using jQuery... did you correctly include jQuery on the page.

Comment: You are passing an object

Comment: Add error handling. Look at the error. Problem solved

Comment: @PatrickEvans I just added Jquery CDN still not working.

Comment: @Roysh why everybody else says that I'm passing an object? I'm so confused!

Comment: @FabioMarzocca Ok how can I solve the problem?

Comment: @Blacksun - have you figured it out? If not, let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `)` of `post` and the `}` of the `ApiRequest` function:

```
function ApiRequest() {
    var mydata = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
    $.post(
      myurl,
        JSON.stringify({
          'api_key': api_key,
          'data': mydata,
        })).then(function(sent) { 
          var s = sent
          var obj = JSON.parse(s)
          $('.score').append(obj.results)
        });
}
```

What your code currently does is call `then` on the result of `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pretty sure it's a syntax problem. I came from Python =)

Comment: @Blacksun make sure you have a matching brackets option turned on in your code editor, so that you can see what is matched by closing parens/brackets/braces. This is very useful when you are closing a number of them and can't work out where to place the closing bracket.

Comment: If you use SublimeText do you know any plugin to do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Blacksun I don't use Sublime, but Google brings this up: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter

Comment: Thank you Billy! I appreciate your help.